# Are there any downsides to using a static class with multiple static AsyncTasks?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I made a static class (`NetworkUtils.java`) with a few static AsyncTasks, each sending some data to server and retrieving a response.

It is working great (in a test environment) and it made the code very clean in the Activities:

```
NetworkUtils.SomeNetworkingTaskCallbackInterface callbacks = 
        new NetworkUtils.SomeNetworkingTaskCallbackInterface() {
    @Override
    public void onFinished(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailed() {

    }
};

NetworkUtils.SomeNetworkingTask task = new NetworkUtils.SomeNetworkingTask(callbacks);
task.execute();
```

Now I am doing a little extra research if there is anything wrong with this approach. I've seen a lot of use-cases of nested static AsyncTasks, but I need them completely decoupled and modular, that's why I put them into a separate static class. I can't think of any downside. Can someone more experienced weigh in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only disadvantages I can think about is that you won't have any access to non static members of the parent class. If for example, your static `Async Task` object had an `Activity` parent class you wouldn't be able to call methods that require a `context`. That means you won't be able to start services, activities or broadcast events from the `Async Task`.

However, you could simply pass a context object to the static class to solve that. But then what happens when your `Async Task` takes long and your activity gets destroyed before it's `onFinish` is called?  You're get an error as your context object is from a destroyed activity.

Comment: This is very encouraging. Right now I don't have any need to drag `Context` around, but it is a valid point and something that needs to be noted. Thanks!